# How to use an object to instantiate JUnit class with Runwith annotation?

Tags: java, selenium, junit4

I am using Junit. The requirement is to club many test suites into one. So i used

`@Runwith(Suite.class)`

`@Suite.SuiteClasses({a.class,b.class})`

`class SuiteRunner{}`

There is some condition on success of it and i need to call this class.
I need to instantiate an object of this class from different java file in the same package.
something like:

`SuiteRunner suite=new SuiteRunner();`.

But it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could put an `@AfterClass` method in `SuiteRunner`, then use it to update a static field with the information you need. You can then access this static field from the other class.

Comment: Thanks..Got the solution..
`JUnitCore.runClasses(new Class[]{SuiteRunner.class});`